# jxdatepicker with Synthetica Aluoxide look and feel not working

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, swingx, synthetica

I have created a simple frame in netbeans and used `SyntheticaAluOxide` look and feel.

then i added the `JXDatePicker` from palette to frame;

now when i try to run the code. The program is throwing Exception as :

```
UIDefaults.getUI() failed: no ComponentUI class for: org.jdesktop.swingx.JXMonthView[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=0,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
java.lang.Error
    at javax.swing.UIDefaults.getUIError(UIDefaults.java:731)
    at javax.swing.MultiUIDefaults.getUIError(MultiUIDefaults.java:130)
    at javax.swing.UIDefaults.getUI(UIDefaults.java:761)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.getUI(UIManager.java:1013)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.plaf.LookAndFeelAddons.getUI(LookAndFeelAddons.java:383)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.JXMonthView.updateUI(JXMonthView.java:789)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.JXMonthView.<init>(JXMonthView.java:320)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.JXMonthView.<init>(JXMonthView.java:257)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.JXDatePicker.initMonthView(JXDatePicker.java:361)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.JXDatePicker.init(JXDatePicker.java:353)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.JXDatePicker.<init>(JXDatePicker.java:281)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.JXDatePicker.<init>(JXDatePicker.java:232)
    at com.test.DatePickerDemo.initComponents(DatePickerDemo.java:33)
    at com.test.DatePickerDemo.<init>(DatePickerDemo.java:21)
    at com.test.DatePickerDemo$1.run(DatePickerDemo.java:89)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

I have used the `swingx` library provided by Synthetica. Added Addon jar also.

Please help me out.

Comment: un_rellated 1. SwingX has buil_in support for Substance L&F, rellated, 2. whats happened in the case that you added JXDatePicker to J(X)Panel programatically, not by dragging from SwingX palette, 2. whats J(X)Components type where you added JXDatePicker

Comment: @mKorbel : I am using SyntheticaAluOxide. I tried adding the JXDatePicker programatically. Still I got same Exception

Comment: now I tried : created a jFrame with Synthetica lnf added a button and on action of that button called the other jframe with nimbuzz lnf. It worked but calling frame get stucked. why ???

Comment: SwingX to override BasicXxxUI important is if is works with Metal, Nimbus, Sustance, SystemL&F, if yes then Jyloo probably isn't supported L&F,

Comment: you can to use another Java Calendar, in the case that you bought Jyloo L&F, for example  [JCalendar by Kai Toedter](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/) is one of my favorite and works without focus, highlighter, caret and selection issue with most of L&F as I tried, up to you

Comment: be sure that only @kleopatra can answering support of 3rd. party L&F and SwingX

Comment: i havent purchased yet Jyloo LnF. am using evaluation jar

Comment: `can i forward you my codes` - please not, I'm here only for my enjoy ...., reason why all identifiers in my profile are empty

Comment: could it be that you don't have the beaninfo installed?

Comment: @kleopatra : means i didn't get that. can u clear me that.

Comment: @kleopatra please maybe idiotic question, are 3rd. party L&Fs supported in SwingX, without overrode something

Comment: is there any other way to achieve it.

Comment: @mKorbel it's the other way round: 3rd party LAFs (f.i. Synthetica) support SwingX components (by providing custom ui-delegates/addons as needed)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the details of configuring Netbeans, so can't really help you - was just wildly guessing on a possible reason :-)

Comment: @kleopatra thanks then looks like as SubstanceL&F and available themes (or for sado_maso to change Colors in theme) is proper and direct of ways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for my problem I got from jyloo.com is :

Reply from jyloo.com :

> Generally SwingX support is provided by SyntheticaAddons - so you
>   additionally need SyntheticaAddons.
>       We also recommend to use our `DateComboBox` component instead of `JXDatePicker`.

so I added the `syntheticaAddons.jar` and `syntheticaAluOxideAddon.jar` to my `classpath` and used the `de.javasoft.swing.DateComboBox`.

I worked like charm.

Thanks to all the Supporters from `stackoverflow.com` and jyloo.com support team.

Answer (score 2):

I have had this exception as well, but it some years back already. I remember it because it seems that Synthentica is enforcing the use of its SwingX extention when you only have a license for Synthetica core, and I was "not amused" by that. Turns out that this is not the case (because I'm using Synthetica core + SwingX now), but my memory fails me in how I got rid of that exception. Searchinf through the source code does not help either, so maybe an emailto Jyloo is in order.

Comment: thanx for your answer.. likely I've put a mail to Jyloo likewise. Let's see what comes..If you found some answer let me know.